# How do I upgrade MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.1?

Tags: windows-xp, mysql

I need to upgrade my MySQL installation to version 5.1 from 5.0.37, and I have studied the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/upgrading.html) and performed all the necessary preliminary steps but (call me stupid) I can't find anywhere what one actually has to do to perform the upgrade. Presumably software has to be obtained from somewhere and installed. Can anyone direct me to instructions about how to do this? I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: Any reason 5.1? I can find 5.5 easily.

Comment: @KCotreau, I was directed by MySQL Workbench to do this; 5.5 will be fine, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find both.

Here is 5.1:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html

And here is 5.5:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html#downloads

Comment: @Brian Hooper My pleasure, and thank you too.